How to deal with a dd copy from smaller onto a larger disk, now systems won't boot?
I have a 512 GB disk with a Windows partition secured by BitLocker and an Arch Linux / system on another one. I got a new 1 TB disk so I cloned the old one into the new one as usual by using an external case and dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress, however strange things started to happen. EDIT: After trying things, I put the large disk inside the PC, so it's /dev/nvme0n1 (not /dev/sdc anymore)

When choosing Arch from the GRUB, I get
/dev/nvme0n1p5: The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 55039744 blocks
The physical size of the device is 33280000 blocks
 Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!

By booting a Ubuntu live USB I figured I coudn't mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 because the partition table was wrong. I ran gparted and it told me something was wrong and that if I wanted to fix it, which I did. Then I could boot Arch.

When choosing Windows Boot Manager from the BIOS boot selector (I could never set it up as to GRUB to manage both systems: everytime I choose Windows I have to enable Secure Boot and choosing Windows Boot Manager instead of GRUB), I get nothing: just a blink and the BIOS boot selector again, just like when Secure Boot is enabled and I want to boot from a USB.
I tried to fix Windows by using boot-repair from the Ubuntu live USB, but it only gives me

Please enable a repository containing the [grub-efi] packages in the software sources of Arch Linux (rolling) (/dev/nvme0n1p5). Then try again.
and Ubuntu's Software & Updates tells me There are no sources to install software from. The file /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/etc/apt/sources.list does not contain any valid software sources.

I then tried to manually add the Windows entry to the GRUB following https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Windows_installed_in_UEFI/GPT_mode
menuentry "Microsoft Windows 10 UEFI/GPT" --class windows  {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    insmod chain
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root A821-B485
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

And I also added GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false to /etc/default/grub and then grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg while booting Arch. After that, I not only didn't gain access to anything but

I lost the GRUB (selecting GRUB on the BIOS boot selector now only gives a UEFI cursor, a blink, and a restart).

How can I properly clone the small disk into the larger?
Can I get somehow access back to Windows after cloning?
Or can I run boot-repair to fix Arch and Windows?
What is causing the partition size mismatch after I clone the disk?



I've already dd'd the disk a couple times, so I'm getting tired of trying things and failing.
Update 1: Adding gdisk of each disk

New disk (1 TB, /dev/nvme0n1)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: KINGSTON SNV2S1000G                     
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): DC682479-2890-4C72-A987-BC465F870F83
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 997784293 sectors (475.8 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1085439   529.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
   2         1085440         1290239   100.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   3         1290240         1323007   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   4         1323008       308523007   146.5 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   5       308523008       574763007   127.0 GiB   8300  arch
   6       574763008       851243007   131.8 GiB   8300  home
   7       895715328       897812479   1024.0 MiB  0700  Basic data partition
   8       897812480       938774527   19.5 GiB    8300  
   9       938774528      1000215175   29.3 GiB    A503  FreeBSD


Old disk (512 GB, /dev/sdc)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000215216 sectors, 476.9 GiB
Model: RTL9210 NVME    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/2048 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): DC682479-2890-4C72-A987-BC465F870F83
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1000215182
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 44474341 sectors (21.2 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1085439   529.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
   2         1085440         1290239   100.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   3         1290240         1323007   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   4         1323008       308523007   146.5 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   5       308523008       574763007   127.0 GiB   8300  arch
   6       574763008       851243007   131.8 GiB   8300  home
   7       895715328       897812479   1024.0 MiB  0700  Basic data partition
   8       897812480       938774527   19.5 GiB    8300  
   9       938774528      1000215175   29.3 GiB    A503  FreeBSD

Update 2: gdisk of original 512 GB disk while connected internally
% sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1                                                                                                                                      
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1000215216 sectors, 476.9 GiB
Model: INTEL SSDPEKKF512G7L                    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): DC682479-2890-4C72-A987-BC465F870F83
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1000215182
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 44474341 sectors (21.2 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1085439   529.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
   2         1085440         1290239   100.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   3         1290240         1323007   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   4         1323008       308523007   146.5 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   5       308523008       574763007   127.0 GiB   8300  arch
   6       574763008       851243007   131.8 GiB   8300  home
   7       895715328       897812479   1024.0 MiB  0700  Basic data partition
   8       897812480       938774527   19.5 GiB    8300  
   9       938774528      1000215175   29.3 GiB    A503  FreeBSD


You copied from /dev/nvme0n1 to /dev/sdc and now there are problems with /dev/nvme0n1? Please confirm. Or is the problematic nvme0n1 the disk that used to be sdc? The question is not clear. Did you replace the old device with the new? Or did you try to boot from the old one (possibly with the new one connected)? Or did you try to boot from the new one (still in the external case)? Please [edit] and clarify.

I suggest you a command grub-install --root-directory=xxx /dev/hdc where xxx is a mountpoint of /dev/hdc

@KamilMaciorowski Thanks for noticing, I missed something important! I swapped disks, so the larger one is the one I tried to boot from (sdc became nvme0n1). The old one I keep safe as backup.

@KamilMaciorowski Done. I'm seeing there's physical sector size mismatch (512/2048), but I don't understand yet what does it mean.

Can you show a gdisk output of the old disk connected internally (i.e. not via USB converter)? I'm mostly interested in seeing what logical sector size it will show.

@grawity_u1686 There it is. I'm seeing that both the logical and physical sector sizes matches as connected externally (512/512).

Logical/physical mismatch isn't a problem in itself, as most things work exclusively in terms of logical sectors. What's important is that the logical sector size matches itself – some USB adapters lie about it – so if the disk reports 512b logical when connected both ways, that should be good enough...

I dd'd the smaller disk into the larger one yet another time, and this time no errors appeared: the Arch system booted correctly. Now the Windows system asks for the BitLocker password each time I boot, which is tedious, but I'm taking it as a security plus.
As I don't know what might be the original cause of the booting malfunction and partition errors, I'm attributing those to possible errors when using dd as I didn't verify for copy errors after each dump, (no checksums or anything whatsoever). Thanks for your help!
